# Access server.xml content during servlet startup

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, initialization, metadata, init

I have an existing servlet and want to write some instructions to my log file on how to construct the URL needed to access my service .  The basic logging service in J2EE is just fine for my purposes.  The items I need are:

1. the canonical host name (got it)
2. the port number(s) for http connectors found in the server.xml file
3. the intermediate path to my servlet (servlet installation folder), 
                e.g. http://host:port/**intermediate path**/additional path

Using these three pieces of information I should be able to leave a breadcrumb of sorts in the log that tells administrators exactly how to configure my client-side app to access to this particular servlet instance.

Getting this information from within my implementation of HttpServlet.service() seems simple but I want to display the data during startup.  **Any thought on how to get it from within my implementation of HttpServlet.init()**?

Comment: what application server are you using?  Server.xml is not a standard part of J2EE, so the answer to your question will vary depending on what sort of server.xml you are dealing with.

Comment: I am using Tomcat 6 and 7 but the servlet will need to deploy to Glassfish, WAS and others.  It actually works in WAS and TOMCAT at this time.  I guess server.xml is implementation specific.  What I was hoping for is to find the information at startup using standard Java J2EE classes and methods.